# Problem with a NSMutableArray Leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

I thought I knew how to deal with memory leaks and arrays, but then this pops up. I can't figure pout why this is leaking:

```
//  MyViewController.h

NSMutableArray      *myMutableArray;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myMutableArray;

//  MyViewController.m

@synthesize myMutableArray;

- (void) viewDidLoad {

    if (self.myMutableArray == nil) {
        self.myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    . . .

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < someCount; ++i) {

        [self.myMutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",myString]];

    }

}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.myMutableArray = nil
}

- (void)dealloc {
     [myMutableArray release];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if (self.myMutableArray == nil) {
    self.myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

It should be:

```
if (myMutableArray == nil) {
   self.myMutableArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

Or:

```
if (myMutableArray == nil) {
   myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Explanation:

Since you are using `retain` as a property mutator attribute, the object will be retained when it is passed to the property setter, therefore you have a leak when you `retain` an object you already have ownership of.

The solution to this is to either a) Pass an `autorelease`-d object to the property setter or b) Assign the ivar directly to the alloc-ed object.

Comment: The second example you give above, the one without the autorelease, you're just dropping the self. from my construction. That's enough to cause it to leak?

Comment: @Lauren, When you assign it directly (without using `self`), you bypass the property setter. The example I provided does not leak, because it assigns an owned object directly instead of retaining it again like the property setter does.

Comment: So assuming I use: if (myMutableArray == nil) {
   myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
} (without the self.) I then can safely refer to it in later code as self.myMutableArray?

Comment: @Lauren, As long as the associated property getter is accessing the same instance variable, absolutely.

Comment: Jacob, EXTREME thanks for making this so clear. I just read your profile. VERY cool! Especially your highlighted Stack Overflow answers. Thanks!

Comment: Not to open a whole other can of worms, but how would referencing my array as self.myMutableArray in the same view controller .m class NOT be accessing the same instance variable? I mean, how easy is it for me to get into trouble doing that?

Comment: @Lauren, You could re-define your getter to return something other than that instance variable. It would be a bit stupid, but I've seen it done before.

Answer (score 2):

You're allocating a new array, then setting it to a retain property. Change that line to

```
self.myMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Comment: Thanks. I learned above that self. initializes it. I learn something new all the time.

Comment: Not quite. Calling `self.myMutableArray = ?` is exactly equivalent to `[self setMyMutableArray:?]`. Since that property is declared as a retain property, you are retaining any object you pass to that method.

Comment: `[NSMutableArray array]` from my answer is exactly equivalent to `[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]` from @Jacob's answer, it's just a shorthand way of returning a new autoreleased mutable array.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

should be

```
self.myMutableArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

because myMutableArray is a retained property.

Comment: But I can manually release a retained property, so I'm not clear why I'd want to simply make it autoreleased? I prefer to maintain control over my properties.